Java Runner in VS Code Runs Code Before Saving File
I’ve encountered an issue when running Java code in vscode. When I haven't manually saved my Java file but click the "Run Java" button, the Java runner executes the code before automatically saving the file. As a result, it runs an outdated version of the code.
BTW, I’m completely new to Java, and I think I’ve followed every step in the docs, but I’m not sure if I missed something during the setup. And I have no idea if it's about vscode itself or Java extention in vscode.
Is there a setting or configuration in vscode or the Java extension to ensure that the file is saved first, before running the code?
I tried asking AI for help, and it suggested turning on the auto-save setting in VS Code. However, I personally don't like this solution because I believe the issue is more of a logical flaw in the process rather than something related to settings.
The issue is that the Java runner executes the code before saving the file, even though the expected behavior should be to save the file first before running the code.

The issue you’re facing occurs because the Java extension in VS Code doesn't always enforce saving the file before running it, depending on your configuration. This is a logical gap, but you can resolve it by adjusting your settings or workflows without enabling auto-save globally. Here's how to address it:
--Open File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl + ,).
--Search for "Save Before Run" in the settings search bar.
--Enable the setting java.debug.saveBeforeStart:
---Go to Extensions > Java Configuration.
---Find Debug: Save Before Start and ensure it’s set to true.
This forces the Java Debugger to save all files before launching.

I have tried but none of them worked, because no such settings exist.
